# How can "localhost" give an answer when apache2 is not installed?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost

My apache2 configuration is driving me crazy, and since I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu (16.04) and servers, I've been trying to install/remove lamp (and also xampp, and also phpmyadmin) a great number of times now, with several methods... without much results.

However, my current configuration is :

- mysql-server is installed, and I can connect with 'mysql -u root -p'
- phpmyadmin : I have tried to reinstall it, but there was a problem with apache2 (could not reload it or something... I haven't figured it yet)
- php7 is installed and has been working until my server has crashed (I haven't tried to remove it)
- apache2 : I used to have a lamp configuration + XAMPP (lampp in /opt/), but since there has been a problem, I uninstalled XAMPP and recently I also unistalled apache2 (sudo apt-get purge apache2, sudo apt-get autoremove, sudo apt-get clean and I verified that the configuration files have been deleted).

When I still had apache2, I finally had this problem : when opening "localhost" on Firefox, it was showing :

```html
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.<br>
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

**My main question for this post now** :

Since I have deleted Apache2, "localhost" should not be working at all now on my browser (Firefox)... However, I still get the exact same page ?! **Do you know why / can help me ?**

Thanks a lot in advance to all who can help me, either to understand my problem better (so that I know a bit more where/how to search for answers), or to solve my problem (and help me work on my website again ^^) !

Answer (score 0):

Have you already stopped Apache via systemctl?  Something like `sudo service stop apache2` (or is it `sudo service apache2 stop`), will stop the server from running.  Even though you have uninstalled everything, the server process will still run if you haven't stopped it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just tried it, but I get the following answer from my console : "Failed to stop apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not loaded."

Comment: Hmm.  Apache could be under another name.  Maybe it's just `apache` or it could even be `httpd`.  I use Arch primarily, so I'm kind of just guessing :).   I would just restart your system and see if the localhost page still shows up after logging back in.   If it does, check that you don't have any other servers installed (like nginx, etc).  If that's not the case, check that your XAMPP installation has been fully uninstalled.  That program is usually bundled together on its own and often times bypasses the system package manager.   Just check /opt and make sure the XAMPP folders are gone.

Comment: Thank you, I have restarted my computer and this problem has disappeared :-) I still have other problems (mainly with phpmyadmin), but apache is working again !